# replace html entities in posts between pre tags

Tags: syntax-highlighting, customization, pre

I run a wordpress [blog](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/) with a syntax highlighter plugin ([Crayon](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/)). The plugin highlights code between pre tags, example:

```
<pre class="lang:languageid" title="example">
some code
</pre>
```

Wordpress sometimes replaces characters suchs as `" & < >` with html entities which are shown in the code `&quot;` `&amp;` etc. I tried several plugins that should prevent this but they don't (always) work.

Is there an easy method to bulk edit old posts and search for entities between `pre` tags en replace them with the character? Or would it be easier to use a replace function on display and replace entities with their characters?

Any suggestions to prevent this in the future are welcome as well (perhaps extend/modify crayon?).

I usually write my blogs with Windows Live Writer but the behaviour also occurs when editing posts with the builtin editor.

Comment: Are the invalid attributes required or an accident?

Comment: I think those are accidents :)

Comment: sorry for the typos, I corrected them...

Comment: Have you tried Raw HTML and wrapping your <pre> blocks in the Raw HTML tag provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers are not the full solution, seems that if I combine them I am very close (just need to fix the replace part). The regex from @hasinhayder answer seems to work well in the plugin that @nathanpowell suggested.

There is no way to split points, [common best practice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13413/how-do-i-combine-two-answers-to-create-the-best-answer-on-stackoverflow#224325) seems to be to combine both answer in your answer and accept that one. I hope that's ok for both?

The answer is then:

Use the [Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) plugin for wordpress and use a regex expression `|<pre.*>(.*)</pre|isU` to match html entities within pre tags.

Answer (score 1):

This one should work

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'pre_content_filter', 0 );

function pre_content_filter( $content ) {
    return preg_replace_callback( '|<pre.*>(.*)</pre|isU' , 'convert_pre_entities', $content );
}

function convert_pre_entities( $matches ) {
    return str_replace( $matches[1], html_entity_decode( $matches[1] ), $matches[0] );
}
```

Let me know

Comment: It will still work because the preg_replace_callback will match all instances of <pre>..</pre>

Comment: what's a good place (file) to put this in?

Comment: inside the functions.php inside the current theme you are using

Comment: it seems to miss "double encoding" for example `&amp;quot;` can it be extended to catch that as well?

Comment: if you just run the convert_pre_entities (or html_entity_decode) once again, it will remove the double encodings. easy

Comment: Doesn't seem to work but will do more testing first...

Comment: Can't get this to work...

Answer (score 1):

WordPress replaces those characters when you are in the VISUAL editor. If you are writing a bunch of code, turn it off, and only write/save in the TEXT or HTML view.

EDIT:
I just realized the "bulk edit" part of this question. I use a scary but powerful plugin called [Search Regex](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) for this type of thing.

Comment: This plugin sounds like it could do the job, did you use a regex for it?

Comment: It will find/replace ANY string essentially. Type the string you are looking for eg:`&amp;` and click FIND. It will show you every occurrence in the database. You can at that point choose to replace with the `&` symbol.

Comment: Seems better to limit this to entities within pre tags, the regex from @hasinhayder's answer nicely select the pre block(s) but how to find the entities in them and replace?

Comment: The plugin will allow you to do a regular expression. I am not savy on that, but here is a good reference http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html