# How to check a filter are applied

Tags: filters

I want to apply this filter from [this question.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91720/replace-html-entities-in-posts-between-pre-tags)

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'pre_content_filter', 0 );

function pre_content_filter( $content ) {
    return preg_replace_callback( '|<pre.*>(.*)</pre|isU' , 'convert_pre_entities', $content );
}

function convert_pre_entities( $matches ) {
    return str_replace( $matches[1], html_entity_decode( $matches[1] ), $matches[0] );
}
```

But it seems there is no effect. So I want to check if the function `pre_content_filter` is really applied. How can I do it?

I've tried `debug-bar` and `debug-bar-extender`, but I couldn't find if I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `has_filter()` to check for registered filers.

Example:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) 
{
    if ( has_filter( 'the_content', 'pre_content_filter' ) )
        return 'pre_content_filter() is active<br>' . $content;

    return $content;
}, -1 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find out all the functions hooked into a particular "filter" and check if a particular function is in that list. Below function returns the list of all functions hooked into a specific filter hook.

```
function get_filters_for( $hook = '' ) {
    global $wp_filter;
    if( empty( $hook ) || !isset( $wp_filter[$hook] ) )
        return;

    return $wp_filter[$hook];
}
```

Call it like this and run a loop to check if the function is in this list.

```
get_filters_for( 'the_content' );
```

Comment: Didn't realize @toscho has already answered !!

Comment: Thanks Subharanjan! I tried to use your function in Debug Bar Console plugin by pasting function and run `var_dump(get_filters_for( 'the_content' ));`, but it shows nothing. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Tetsu Just removed an extra parenthesis from the return statement. It works now.. Please check. :) 
http://awesomescreenshot.com/06e22nqdbd